# How can I crop in batch in Photoshop or Lightroom and remove edges?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, cropping

I have several images I want to crop in batch. They are scans and have "jagged edges". Basically I just want a 95% crop in both directions with the crop frame perfectly centered. So if the image is 1000x1000, I want a 950x950 image with 25 pixels cropped from each side. I don't see a way to specify this in Photoshop or Lightroom. Note: I do NOT want to straighten or resize the image.

Comment: ImageMagick's `mogrify` or `convert` tools might be a better fit for this, with a little scripting...

Comment: You need to record an action in PS of you doing these commands, then run it as a batch from Adobe Bridge. I don't have the specifics of those instructions so I won't write this as an actual answer right now. Consider it a hint.

Comment: I disagree with the dupe. Nothing in the duped question addresses the need to crop at 95%. Brian, if the linked question doesn’t help you, please let us know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use XNView MP for this purpose.

1. Select the images you want to crop
   [image]
2. Select Crop action, select from edge and add 25 to all field
   [image]
3. Select where you want to be stored result files (filenames, path, etc)
   [image]
4. Press Convert button

Answer (score 0):

Will update with images later, on mobile now.

Record an action where you adjust the canvas size: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/adjusting-crop-rotation-canvas.html

Anchor in the center and adjust width and height to -5%.

I would advise making a backup copy of your original files folder before applying any actions, even if saving to a different destination. You know, just in case.